# Can I prevent a Youtube embed iframe to scroll into view when interacted with? It breaks my accordion

Tags: html, css

I have this accordion which basically consists of an **outer** div with a set `height` and `overflow-y: hidden`, and an **inner** div with dynamic content fed from a CMS (and a button to remove the height and overflow-rules from the outer div, very simplified).

Sometimes the content in the inner div contain an embedded Youtube video (iframe). Whenever the Youtube video is being "cut off" by the outer div's `overflow-y: hidden`, a problem occurs. When you start interacting with the video, giving it focus by clicking play, stop et.c., the video scrolls into view and any content placed above the video might disappear out above the upper edge of the outer div thus becoming invisible. It is not possible to scroll it back into view, as the outer div has `overflow-y: hidden` which disables the scrolling just like expected - but apparently not when giving focus to the video.

Is there a way to prevent the scrolling of the divs when giving the video focus? Apparently `overflow-y: hidden` is not enough. I have faced this problem in Chrome. In Firefox, it seems to work fine by default - no scrolling occurs when fiddling with the video.

*If possible, I'm looking for a CSS only solution, preferably no JS.*

I have created a codepen to illustrate the problem where you can see it in action: https://codepen.io/monodrive/pen/poEraWK

The very simplified code looks like this (the accordion functionality has been completely left out since it's not relevant for reproducing this behaviour).

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">
    Hello there. This text comes from the inner div. It will scroll out of the viewport once you start interacting with the Youtube video below, and cannot be scrolled into view again. Can the initial scroll be prevented? (seems to happen in Chrome only)<br>
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/DWcJFNfaw9c" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
  max-height: 250px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that there's a simple way to avoid auto-scrolling to the video after playing it. It looks like a tiny UX optimization from the browser. But there's a thing that I don't understand in the UI in the demo: why there's no scroll and at the same time the inner content is bigger than the viewport. I think an issue is there. User sees a content but cannot normally interact with it.

Comment: May be the proper solution is to have "overflow: auto" or "overflow: scroll". But I think you did it intentionally. So there's an idea behind it. Could you please clarify why "overflow: hidden" was used? 

Now I can offer you only that: add "onClick" handler to the iframe tag. In the event handler read "scrollTop" of the container. Then in the next tick (e.g. setTimeout) recover it.

Comment: @faiwer there is a reason for my "overflow: hidden" - the inner/outer div layout is supposed to constitute an accordion, where all the content of variable height is present in the inner div, but partly hidden by the "overflow: hidden" in combination with the max-height on the outer div. I omitted the code for expanding the accordion though, just to simplify the example. I think that you are right, this is probably an obscure way by the browser to try to "help" with the UX.

Comment: @faiwer a very similar problem could occur if there were links (a-tags) in the hidden content and you would use the tab key to navigate. Eventually a hidden link would scroll into view when focused, and there would be no way to manually scroll back to the top within the div. I have mitigated this by setting tabindex="-1" on all hidden links with a small script, whether that's a good solution or not is another discussion, but it might be easier to visualize the issue when thinking of links instead of a Youtube embed.

Comment: To be honest, I still don't understand why do you want to have "partly hidden" content without a scroll. Because It makes it unusable for users. Or is scrollbar okay for your task?

Comment: As I understood: you want to avoid extending "height" for the both containers (so you used `overflow: hidden`). Somehow restrict it. And "max-height" alone won't help you with it, but in a combination with "overflow: auto" or "overlflow-y: scroll" it would work. It also makes a vertical scrollbar. So user can scroll it.

Comment: If you want anyway to show it only partially and at the same time disable any possibility of scrolling this... I think the only way to do it firmly is to listen to javascript events. E.g. `onScroll` and "fix" scroll to `0`.

Comment: Something like 'onScroll="event => event.currentTarget.scrollTop = 0"` or the like

Comment: @faiwer it's supposed to be an accordion with a "show more" button at the bottom, i.e. some of the contents is visible from start and then there's a button to click to view it all. I'm not sure I can explain it in a better way. I think it's not an uncommon feature, often seen in product pages on e-commerce sites etc. Anyway your javascript suggestion seems like it might fix it so I'll give it a try. Thanks!